# Android: spinner with option group (no ExpandableListView)

Tags: android, spinner

how is possible to create a spinner with subcategories?

Without using ExpandableListView, just a single spinner-option group.

Eg.

```
NUMBERS (unselectable)
    1
    2
    3
LETTERS (unselectable)
    a
    b
    c
```

Comment: have you got any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Android section-list](https://code.google.com/p/android-section-list/) (a ListView divided in sections), it might do the trick for you.

Comment: But its not drop down like a spinner

Comment: NO LONGER MAINTAINED. (Support stopped ~7 years ago.)